What is the size of an adversary?
I was reading a SMPC paper, and it writes that "non-uniform adversary A of size $\text{poly}(λ)$".
What is the size of adversary in secure multiparty computation, and where can I find some reference papers that explicitly explain this definition?

The important term here is "non-uniform" which comes from computational complexity theory:

A "uniform" algorithm is one with a finite description size that works for all input lengths. For example, a Turing machine is a model of uniform computation.

A "non-uniform" algorithm is really a collection of different algorithms for different input lengths. Since there are infinitely many possible input lengths, a non-uniform "algorithm" has infinite description size.


The standard example of a model of uniform computation is a Turing machine.
The standard example of non-uniform computation is a boolean circuit (family). A boolean circuit has a fixed number of input wires, so it can only handle a single input length. Thus, if we want to talk about circuits solving problems in the standard asymptotic, computational-complexity sense (decision problems where the input lengths have unbounded length), we would need to specify an entire family of circuits, one for each input length.
In the context of cryptography, a non-uniform adversary is a boolean circuit that is fixed for a particular value of the security parameter.
In a Turing machine, we can measure its efficiency by its running time. But a boolean circuit doesn't really have running time. Instead, we measure its efficiency by its size = number of boolean gates.
Just like running time is often an asymptotic measure (how does the running time scale as the input length approaches infinity?), so is the size of a non-uniform computation: in a given circuit family, how does the size of the circuit scale with the input length?
Why non-uniform adversaries?
In a non-uniform model, we measure efficiency only by the size of the circuit. But there is no restriction on the efficiency of the following problem: given an input length, figure out what the "correct" circuit is for that input length.
This step can even be undecidable, and indeed there are plenty of undecidable problems that can be "solved" by a non-uniform "algorithm." (Hopefully this is not too hard to accept, since a non-uniform algorithm can have an infinitely large description.)
Anyway, you can think of a non-uniform adversary as one that has access to an unlimited amount of pre-computation that depends only on the security parameter.
In other words, the security parameter is chosen, then an unbounded amount of computation goes into determining which circuit to use in an attack.
The only restriction is that the size of this circuit must be polynomial in the security parameter.

Thanks a lot for you answer!
BTW, is there any paper or textbook that I can refer to?
